# How can I Display a JavaScript ES6 Map Object to Console?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, console.log, ecmascript-2016

I'm using  [repl.it/languages/javascript](http://repl.it/languages/javascript).

Do I have to convert it to an object before I print it out?

I've tried

```js
    const mapObject = new Map();
    
    mapObject.set(1, 'hello');
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mapObject));
    console.log(mapObject);
```

The results are always empty object.

When I use

```
console.log([...mapObject]);
```

It prints out an array format.

Comment: `console.log(mapObject)` works just fine in the latest Chrome and node7. What's your platform?

Comment: @georg https://repl.it/languages/javascript

Comment: Use `console.dir` instead of `.log`, and without stringifying.

Comment: @newguy: well, how about you drop them a line and ask to fix that?

Comment: @georg I still see empty objects on my browser after your edit.

Comment: @newguy: yep, this is because SO snippets got it wrong too. Emulating the console is hard...

Comment: @georg :( so it's not my problem? I am glad to know that. But that's really annoying thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: This answer is only relevant to the repl.it sandbox environment OP is using**

Since you said in the comments that you're using [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/javascript), there's a trick you can use to write your own "logging strategy".

Note that you shouldn't use this trick in production, mainly because it edits a native prototype. In some Node environment, in your own code, it could be useful though.

The idea is to create an `inspect` method for `Map` that iterates over the `entries`:

```
Map.prototype.inspect = function() {
  return `Map(${mapEntriesToString(this.entries())})`
}

function mapEntriesToString(entries) {
  return Array
    .from(entries, ([k, v]) => `\n  ${k}: ${v}`)
    .join("") + "\n";
}
```

You can see that repl.it supports it **[here](https://repl.it/KBcn)**

```
console.log(new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]));
// Logs:
/*
Map(
  a: 1
  b: 2
)
*/
```

Comment: Nice one. I just finished something similar, but I chose to bastardise their `console.log` instead :) https://repl.it/KBdU

Comment: @DaveSalomon Nice! Feels like "We're in an online sandbox environment; let's break *all* the native prototypes and default implementations!" ;) Still, both approaches can help in the debugging process, so it's nice to see what can be done.

Answer (score 60):

There is a more simpler solution you can try.

```js
const mapObject = new Map();
mapObject.set(1, 'hello');

console.log([...mapObject.entries()]);
// [[1, "hello"]]

console.log([...mapObject.keys()]);
// [1]

console.log([...mapObject.values()]);
// ["hello"]
```

Comment: Works well with stringify: console.log( JSON.stringify([... mapObject.entries()]) )

Comment: If I try this, I get an error saying "Type 'IterableIterator<string>' is not an array type". OK, in my case the Map ist more complicated than that defined in the snippet. But if the solution only works for those simple Maps it's not worth considering.

Answer (score 7):

For simple maps that are of depth 1, just use `Object.fromEntries([...map])` to convert your object entries array back to a console loggable object:

```js
const simpleObj = {
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: {c: {d: 42}}
};
const map = new Map(Object.entries(simpleObj));
console.log(Object.fromEntries([...map]));
```

This fails for complex nested maps, however. For that, we can recursively convert any `Map`s to objects and then log it as normal. Here's a proof-of-concept on a complex structure combining plain objects, `Map`s, arrays and primitives. Don't expect it to cover every edge case out of the box, but feel free to point out improvements.

```js
const convertMapToObjDeeply = o => {
  const recurseOnEntries = a => Object.fromEntries(
    a.map(([k, v]) => [k, convertMapToObjDeeply(v)])
  );
  
  if (o instanceof Map) {
    return recurseOnEntries([...o]);
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o.map(convertMapToObjDeeply);
  }
  else if (typeof o === "object" && o !== null) {
    return recurseOnEntries(Object.entries(o));
  }
  
  return o;
};

const mkMap = o => new Map(Object.entries(o));

const map = mkMap({
  a: 42, 
  b: [1, 2, 3, mkMap({d: mkMap({ff: 55})})],
  c: mkMap({
    e: [4, 5, 6, {f: 5, x: y => y}, mkMap({g: z => 1})]
  }),
  h: {i: mkMap({j: 46, jj: new Map([[[1, 6], 2]])})},
  k: mkMap({l: mkMap({m: [2, 5, x => x, 99]})})
});

console.log(convertMapToObjDeeply(map));
```

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is most likely intended for the browser console but this also occurs in Node. So, you may use this in Node to view Maps (or an Object that may contain Maps):

```
import * as util from "util";

const map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
map.set("test", "test");

const inspected: string = util.inspect(map);

console.log(inspected);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest *and* most human readable option: `console.table`

```
const mapObject = new Map();
mapObject.set(1, 'hello');
mapObject.set(2, 'world');
mapObject.set('foo', 'bar');

console.table(mapObject);
```

NodeJS output looks like this:

```
┌───────────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ (iteration index) │  Key  │ Values  │
├───────────────────┼───────┼─────────┤
│         0         │   1   │ 'hello' │
│         1         │   2   │ 'world' │
│         2         │ 'foo' │  'bar'  │
└───────────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Chrome dev tools console output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let mapObject = new Map();
mapObject.set("one", "file1");
mapObject.set("two", "file2");
mapObject.set("three", "file3");
console.log([...mapObject.entries()]);
```

the output will be:

```
[ [ 'one', 'file1' ], [ 'two', 'file2' ], [ 'three', 'file3' ] ]
```

The problem with this solution, is that the output changes if we add a previous string:

```
console.log("This is a map: " + [...mapObject.entries()]);
```

the output will be:

```
This is a map: one,file1,two,file2,three,file3
```

the solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866854/convert-to-string-a-map-similar-to-console-output-via-console-log-mapobject/69866872#69866872)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `console.log(mapObject.values())`

Comment: All I see from this is `[object Map Iterator] {}`, in the CodePen console anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (regular browser console in Chrome V 115, Immutable Map) I could use

```
console.dir(myMapObject.toJS());
```

It contained a great deal of information more than I needed, but better too much than too little.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script to convert the map to a array and print it.
Make sure that the entries in the map can be stringified.

```
function printMap(map) {
  const entries = map.entries();

    const arr = new Array();

    let entry = entries.next();

    while (!entry.done) {
      arr.push({ [entry.value[0]]: entry.value[1] });

      entry = entries.next();
    }

    return arr;
    
}
```