# Convert to String a map similar to console output via console.log([...mapObject.entries()])

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following map:

```
  let mapObject = new Map();
  mapObject.set("one", "file1");
  mapObject.set("two", "file2");
  mapObject.set("three", "file3");

  console.log([...mapObject.entries()]);
```

and the console generates the following output:

```
[ [ 'one', 'file1' ], [ 'two', 'file2' ], [ 'three', 'file3' ] ]
```

I took this idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571101/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-es6-map-object-to-console), but this solution doesn't work if you add a string in the console statement:

```
console.log("This is a map: " + [...mapObject.entries()]);
```

it generates the following output instead:

```
This is a map: one,file1,two,file2,three,file3
```

which is less friendly to read. I would like in some how to have the same output I would obtain from: `console.log([...mapObject.entries()])` but to be able to store it in a string for a general purpose. Is there a simple way to achieve it that works for google apps script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
let mapObject = new Map();
mapObject.set("one", "file1");
mapObject.set("two", "file2");
mapObject.set("three", "file3");

const res = JSON.stringify([...mapObject.entries()])

console.log("This is a map: " + res);
```

Comment: it works thanks!, I though for this solution I would need to install some JSON library, but it doesn't require any additional setup.