# A class method with a Set collection doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, methods

```
class a {

    public COUNTS = new Set<string>();

    constructor() {
    }

    public execute(): any {

        this.COUNTS.add('a');
        this.COUNTS.add('b');

        console.log(this.COUNTS);

        return { contas: this.COUNTS };
    }

}

const x = (new a()).execute();

console.log(x);
```

The first console log return the set created as expected, but the second one just return { contas: {} }. I wanna know why this only happens whith SET and MAP.

Comment: I can't precisely replicate this: if I run it in the TS playground I see what you say you get, but if I actually run the code in chrome I get the expected output instead. If you only ever saw that in the TS playground it's an artifact of that environment, but if you see that in a browser or node.js please give us which one and the version.

Comment: I think it might be a quirk of how different console implementations display Sets when logged directly - like @JaredSmith I saw the results you indicated in the TS playground, but when putting it into a snippet here (stripping off the TS parts so it's valid JS), it showed me an empty object for *both* logs. Does it work better if you log `[...x]`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571101/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-es6-map-object-to-console) (about maps rather than sets but you say your issue applies to those too) may possibly be relevant (although I'm not certain).

Comment: Also probably worth noting here that a good bit of the console API is implementation-dependent and IIRC not strictly specified by the standard.

Comment: I just tried it myself (and realised that of course `[...x]` is an error, you need to spread the `this.COUNTS` inside the returned object) - and indeed that gives the expected result, [try running this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEbQ3gKEdV0AOBXARiAlsNAMIDyAqgHIAqAytALzQB2ApgO7Q0sAuAPBNwBOeJgHMAfAAoAlAG5kaaMAD2TAYMzBuywTIQo0AXwVosuAtBYAPFsEzcWMgFywmAT30HFqbgAs8EAB0pJS0gWAAJhGSAORgMXJe3n4BweTUNOFRsdgJ8kmKKmrKICyBIMqikilBIRmJBWiCPJiCTAhKqtyQLgDagQM1aaE0ALrQhvKKxogzRQLQVgzQkqwcYDLSgda29o4N8yVlFVVWckA). So it's 100% a console issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here. What you're seeing is how the tool you're using has decided to represent its output.

In the TS Playground, you see this:

[image]

But if you take the compiled JavaScript code from there and put it here in StackOverflow's snippet, you see this:

[image]

```js
class a {
constructor() {
    this.COUNTS = new Set();
}
execute() {
    this.COUNTS.add('a');
    this.COUNTS.add('b');
    console.log(this.COUNTS);
    return { contas: this.COUNTS };
}
}
const x = (new a()).execute();
console.log(x);
```

But then if you open Chrome dev tools and look at the console output, you see this:

[image]

So it appears that different tools represent the Set in different ways in the console output, and some of them change that representation when the Set is inside of a JavaScript object. The Set should continue to work like a Set, regardless.

If you're building this object to send as a JSON string, note that the JSON representation of a Set object is just `{}`. So you'll probably need to translate it into something serializable like an array, which you can do with the spread operator:

```
return { contas: [...this.COUNTS] };
```

Comment: Now i can see it. I was using this (return { contas: [...this.COUNTS] };), but it did not seem correct. Thanks for helping me!